# how to call https url from shell script

Tags: shell, https

I am working on device which has embeded OS with limited features and space. I am can't install any scripting language like php curl. I would like to know is there any way to call https url with some header values (e.g. content type) using shell script and once get response that can be displayed on web page or can write into file.

Regds

Comment: Do you have curl available to you as a provided utility?

Comment: I do have wget but dont have curl. I already achieve it using curl by setting up local wamp server but my device does not have curl. I will try using wget. but I have doubt, how to send http headers with this and username and password as credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` and `wget`, as already suggested, are usually available in shells. If those are not available you'll have to give more details about your platform to figure out what *could* be available.

Comment: correct but the problem is I do not have curl command for shell in my embed OS I need to use wget at this point in time.

Comment: Since you can use *either*, this is not a problem.

Comment: but wget can be used with HTTP only and not HTTPS. Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It can be used for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try wget like this:

```
wget --http-user=user --http-password=password http://domain.com/dir/file
```